# How to connect to the windows oracle database from WSL2

Tags: oracle, windows-10, sqlplus, remote-access, wsl-2

I have a Oracle 19c database installed in windows10 and also I have WSL2 enabled in same laptop.
I would like to access the database from my WSL2- ubuntu distro. is it possible?
I have installed instantclient and sqlplus package in wsl2 but when I try to connect using sqlplus it couldn't able to connect to the windows database.
can someone please help me to connect to that database from WSL2?

```
sqlplus hr/hr@//172.22.100.119/orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jul 1 15:52:02 2022
Version 21.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred


Enter user-name:
```

```
sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jul 1 15:50:31 2022
Version 21.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: spdorcl@orcl
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:
```

```
sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Jul 1 15:48:54 2022
Version 21.6.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: SYSTEM
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name: sys
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Comment: Hey! I've a few leading questions for you:
1) What is written in your tnsnames.ora file in WSL2?
2) Have you tried to ping the server both from Windows and WSL machines?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you comments. I have got it fixed. The issue is in firewall port . I have opened it and it is working fine afterwards.

Comment: Could you explain the principle of working with ports or links to the resources that helped to deal with the issue?

Comment: I Just added oracle port in inbound rule and gave access to all domains (Domain, Private, Public)